# Lighting program - GPIO on/off on raspberry pi runtimewarning

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Hello i have been trying to work this one out by myself for over a week now but i think its time to ask the question.

This is my first program with python and i intend to control my aquarium with various functions.

The first function i am programming is a lighting schedule (shortened the code a bit for this post)

The code executes okay but the GPIO pin 2 isnt turning on and off properly. and im also getting a "runtimewarning this channel is already in use"

Can i please have a bit of guidance, im sure its something simple and noob :)

here is my code

```
#Lighting Program 

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Declare Lighting On/Off Times
on_time_Monday = 600
off_time_Monday = 2330
```

rest of the days here

```
#Find out what day of the week it is
day = datetime.datetime.now()
day_of_week = day.isoweekday()

#find out what time it is
Current_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(),'%H%M')

#convert the time to an int so it can be compared
Current_time_INT = int(Current_time)

#Schedule on / off
if (day_of_week == 1) and (Current_time_INT > on_time_Monday and Current_time_INT < off_time_Monday) :
    Light_on_off = 'on'
```

Using 'elif' for tues wed etc etc

```
else :
    Light_on_off = 'off'
```

Now enable the outputs

```
#CALL OUTPUTS ON / OFF
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT) 

if Light_on_off == 'on':
    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
else:
    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Just a note: you can retrieve a `datetime.time` instance of a `datetime.datetime` class, and then compare them more naturally: `on_time_Monday = datetime.time(8, 12); datetime.datetime.now().time() > on_time_Monday --> True`.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience "runtimewarning this channel is already in use" comes up when you have previously setup the GPIO pin, but haven't called
    GPIO.cleanup().
I see that in your code, but I would suspect that for some reason it is not actually running.

Sometimes it is helpful to test out a GPIO pin in the terminal by running the python interpreter. It is especially useful to test if you have wired your circuit correctly.

```
>>>import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
>>>GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
>>>GPIO.setwarnings(False)
>>>GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
>>>GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
>>>GPIO.input(2)
True
>>>GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
>>>GPIO.input(2)
False
>>>GPIO.cleanup()
```

If your circuit is wired correctly you should be able to turn your light on and off this way. When you call GPIO.input(2) the interpreter responds with the current state of the pin. This enables you to make sure the pin is working even without a working external circuit. Once you know that it is working you can move on from there.

One simple way to flip a light switch on and off would be to use cron jobs. I have used this method successfully in the past.

You can write two short scripts, one that turns the light on, and one that turns it off.

Example: lightOn.py (replace 'HIGH' with 'LOW' for lightOff.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Now you can [create a crontab](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md) to automatically run the script at the times you want.
For example:

```
0 6 * * *  /home/pi/lightOn.py
0 18 * * * /home/pi/lightOff.py
```

Would turn the light on everyday at 6AM and off at 6PM